# find each path in SVG image on mouse over

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

This is my code to load SVG image form server .. work well

Now, my problem is :

> 1- How I can find each path in SVG image on mouse over ??? making
>   rectangle on the single path founded.

Then,

> 2- How I can change color for single path selected  by using color
>   picker .

[Example SVG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAe5G.png)

> View

```
<div id="my-div"></div>
```

> JS

```
 src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vivus@latest/dist/vivus.min.js" // usign this script to load SVg

new Vivus('my-div', {
duration: 200,
 file: 'http://www.stirox.com/R/uploads/s.svg'
 }, function() {
  alert(1);
  });
```